# Why does my Python list contain identical elements after each element was mutated in a for-loop?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, variable-assignment

I have a list of three dicts, of which I change values of each dict within a for-loop. Print statements confirm that each loop has altered its corresponding dict (to different values, hence the dicts should not be identical after the for loop). However, once I print the complete list immediately after the for-loop, the list contains identical dicts. My code looks like this:

```
split_tag = []
    for _ in split_polygon: split_tag.append(tag) # len(split_polygon) is 3
print("Initial tags: " + str(split_tag))
for i, pg in enumerate(split_polygon):
    split_tag[i]["polygon"] = pg
    split_tag[i]["bbox"] = bound_box(pg)
    print("Splitted tag " + str(i) + ": " + str(split_tag[i]))
print("Final tags: " + str(split_tag))
```

Python 2.7 and Python 3.5 both give the following output:

```
Initial tags: [{'score': 0, 'polygon': [(1668.0832177531206, 2588.404993065187), (1668.0832177531206, 3662.113730929265), (1175.9667128987517, 3662.113730929265), (1311.0385388560185, 2837.768364063218)], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1175.9667128987517, 2588.404993065187, 492.11650485436894, 1073.7087378640776), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}, {'score': 0, 'polygon': [(1668.0832177531206, 2588.404993065187), (1668.0832177531206, 3662.113730929265), (1175.9667128987517, 3662.113730929265), (1311.0385388560185, 2837.768364063218)], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1175.9667128987517, 2588.404993065187, 492.11650485436894, 1073.7087378640776), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}, {'score': 0, 'polygon': [(1668.0832177531206, 2588.404993065187), (1668.0832177531206, 3662.113730929265), (1175.9667128987517, 3662.113730929265), (1311.0385388560185, 2837.768364063218)], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1175.9667128987517, 2588.404993065187, 492.11650485436894, 1073.7087378640776), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}]
Splitted tag 0: {'score': 0, 'polygon': [[1668, 3662], [1175, 3662], [1247, 3227], [1668, 3191]], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1175, 3191, 493, 471), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}
Splitted tag 1: {'score': 0, 'polygon': [[1409, 3134], [1259, 3155], [1311, 2837], [1344, 2814], [1388, 2933], [1384, 2786], [1430, 2754]], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1259, 2754, 171, 401), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}
Splitted tag 2: {'score': 0, 'polygon': [[1668, 3074], [1486, 2987], [1473, 2724], [1668, 2588]], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1473, 2588, 195, 486), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}
Final tags: [{'score': 0, 'polygon': [[1668, 3074], [1486, 2987], [1473, 2724], [1668, 2588]], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1473, 2588, 195, 486), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}, {'score': 0, 'polygon': [[1668, 3074], [1486, 2987], [1473, 2724], [1668, 2588]], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1473, 2588, 195, 486), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}, {'score': 0, 'polygon': [[1668, 3074], [1486, 2987], [1473, 2724], [1668, 2588]], 'tagname': u'asphalt', 'type': 'MyPolygonItem', 'bbox': (1473, 2588, 195, 486), 'ref_id': 321745191097315359679355396732871380055L}]
```

Printing each dict separately at the end of each loop shows that they have indeed been mutated; at least, the `polygon` and `bbox` values have been. However, printing the whole list at the end shows that the dicts are now suddenly identical, including `polygon` and `bbox`.

Does anyone know why and where my list is secretely being mutated? Does the for-loop perhaps work on some kind of local version of `split_tag`?

For reference, my `bound__box()` function is as follows:

```
def bound_box(coordinate_pairs):
    x_min = 999999
    y_min = 999999
    x_max = 0
    y_max = 0

    for pair in coordinate_pairs:
        if pair[0] < x_min: x_min = pair[0]
        if pair[0] > x_max: x_max = pair[0]
        if pair[1] < y_min: y_min = pair[1]
        if pair[1] > y_max: y_max = pair[1]

    return (x_min, y_min, x_max - x_min, y_max - y_min)
```

Comment: fix: `split_tag = [tag for _ in range(len(split_polygon))]`. or even: `split_tag = [tag for _ in split_polygon]`.

Comment: Thanks! But that still yields the same results, unfortunately. I also tried initializing as ```split_tag = [], for _ in split_polygon: split_tag.append(tag)```, which also doesn't work, for both Python 2.7 and 3.5.

Comment: oops! ok, then please fix that in your question and i will reopen the question... (also add `bounding_box` in order to make it a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Done, and no problem! I would've sworn that that should have been the solution.

Comment: `split_tag.append(tag)` in the beginning should be `split_tag.append(deepcopy(tag))`, where deepcopy is a concept, not a specific method

Comment: ah, `tag` is mutable... did not see that at first glance.